# Android - do ViewGroup onDraw need to iterate through child view and call onDraw explicitly?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, viewgroup

I have spent the whole day debugging various ways to add custom `ViewGroup` into another custom `ViewGroup` and nearly went crazy because none of them works, and there is no official documentation or sample that shows how it can be done...

Basically, I have 2 custom `ViewGroup`:

1. `HorizontalDockView` extends `ViewGroup`
2. `GameEntryView` extends `FrameLayout`

`HorizontalDockView` overrides `onDraw`, `onMeasure`, etc and everything is called normally and works perfectly.
However, when I create `GameEntryView` from inside `HorizontalDockView`'s constructor and call `addView(gameEntryView)`, the `gameEntryView` will never ever show regardless of the `layoutParams`, `addView` called from whatever thread, or however I call, load, and setContentView on the parent `HorizontalDockView`. If I list through the `horizontalDockView.getChildAt();` all the `gameEntryView` objects are still there.

Hopeless, I try to debug through GameEntryView's `onDraw`, `onMeasure`, `dispatchDraw` methods and realized none of them actually get called! No.. not even once!

Do I need to iterate through all the child view in the parent (HorizontalDockView's) on* call and call the children's on* explicitly? I was just calling super.on*() on the parent.

I did call `setWillNotDraw( false );` on both the parent and the child class.

How do I get the child to show up inside the parent's view? simple sample or existing small open source project is highly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you overwrite `onLayout`? When Android lays out your `ViewGroup`, your `ViewGroup` is responsible for laying out the children.

This code is from a custom ViewGroup that lays out all children on top of each other:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b) {

    int count = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        View child = this.getChildAt(i);
        child.layout(0, 0, child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

For completeness, the `onMeasure` override:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int parentWidth  = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);

    int count = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        View child = this.getChildAt(i);
        this.measureChild(
            child,
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I override onLayout and onMeasure on the child view class, but I did not override onLayout on parent view class! I called super.onMeasure() on parent view class but apparently that is not working. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!

Comment: Hi @FabianZeindl, what if I want the children to layout sequentially like LinearLayout instead of overlapping each other?

Comment: Android layouting is really complicated there (because of display fragmentation and over-generalizing everything). You can just adapt your onLayout to give other positions and sizes to your children, which you calculate beforehand. It takes a good implementation of the onMeasure method that your children "behave" and display the right way as well. Just try it.