# Android layout not aligned parent as instructed in java code

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am having problem inflating my CustomView programmatically from the XML layout that I specify.

I have a CustomView which extends RelativeLayout and contains another RelativeLayout which in turns contain 2 ImageView and 1 LinearLayout. The ImageViews are arrow Icons which I put to the left and right of the parent by android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and android:layout_alignParentRight="true" respectively, and the LinearLayout is used to fill all the space in between.

To make it clear, here is the xml layout view in the Eclipse Layout Designer, which is what I intended it to be...

[image: my_xml_layout - which is what I'd like it to be]

If I setContentView(R.layout.my_xml_layout); directly from the Activity, everything appears as shown in Eclipse Layout Designer, however, if I inflate the R.layout.my_xml_layout from my CustomView's constructor, there is a stubborn margin to the left and right of the ImageView that cannot go away.

This is done in java code, and is problematic:

[image: As you can see, there is the stubborn spacing to the left of the left ImageView and to the right of the right ImageView]

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

my_xml_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLeftArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/dock_leftarrow" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageRightArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/dock_rightarrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I inflate it in the CustomView's Constructor through this line:

```
View.inflate( mContext, R.layout.my_xml_layout, this );
```

My CustomView's onLayout:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // Do nothing. Do not call the superclass method--that would start a layout pass
    // on this view's children. PieChart lays out its children in onSizeChanged().
    Log.e("DrawView", "DrawView.onLayout: " + l + ", " + t + ", " + r + ", " + b);

    int iChildCount = this.getChildCount();
    for ( int i = 0; i < iChildCount; i++ ) {
        View pChild = this.getChildAt(i);
        pChild.layout(0, 0, pChild.getMeasuredWidth(), pChild.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

My CustomView's onMeasure:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // Try for a width based on our minimum
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    Log.d("DockView", "DockView.onMeasure: width: " + widthMeasureSpec + " getWidth: " + MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));
    Log.d("DockView", "DockView.onMeasure: height: " + heightMeasureSpec + " getHeight: " + MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
    Log.d("DockView", "DockView.onMeasure: getPaddingLeft: " + getPaddingLeft() + " getPaddingRight: " + getPaddingRight());
    Log.d("DockView", "DockView.onMeasure: getPaddingTop: " + getPaddingTop() + " getPaddingBottom: " + getPaddingBottom());

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545273/474330
    int iParentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int iParentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(iParentWidth, iParentHeight);

    int iChildCount = this.getChildCount();
    for ( int i = 0; i < iChildCount; i++ ) {
        View pChild = this.getChildAt(i);
        this.measureChild( pChild, 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(iParentWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(iParentHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any padding or somehting?

Comment: no, no padding and no margin at all... I doubt it is the onMeasure, because if I comment it out, the ImageView will not show at all... I got the code from another question in StackOverflow and do not really comprehend the way it (MeasureSpec etc) works...

Comment: Remove this line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from your second `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I removed it, and it doesn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, I am resorting to a hack.

I only add the LinearLayout as subview of my CustomView. Then I manually render the two ImageViews in onDraw(Canvas c); function of my CustomView. And in order to get the LinearLayout to fit into the remaining space between the two ImageViews, I calculate the margin of the LinearLayout in my CustomView's onLayout.

horizontal_dock_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/imageLauncher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomView.java

```
    /**
     * Initialize the control. This code is in a separate method so that it can be
     * called from both constructors.
     */
    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw( false );

        // Load the arrow bitmap
        mArrowBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dock_leftarrow)).getBitmap();

        ViewGroup pRootView = (ViewGroup) View.inflate( mContext, R.layout.horizontal_dock_view, this );
        Log.d("DockView", "DockView.init: " + pRootView.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        mIconContainerView = (LinearLayout) ((RelativeLayout)pRootView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);

        Log.d("DockView", "DockView.init: " + mIconContainerView.getClass().getCanonicalName());

//      if ( mArrowBitmap != null ) {
//          // set the icon container margin        
//          float fWidth = this.getWidth();     // View's width
//          float fHeight = this.getHeight();   // View's height
//          float fScale = fHeight / mArrowBitmap.getHeight();
//          float fArrowWidth = mArrowBitmap.getWidth() * fScale;
//          float fArrowHeight = mArrowBitmap.getHeight() * fScale;
//          Log.d("DockView", "DockView.init: " + fArrowWidth + ", " + fArrowHeight );
//          ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mIconContainerView.getLayoutParams()).setMargins((int)fArrowWidth, 0, (int)fArrowWidth, 0);
//      }
    }
```

CustomView.onLayout:

```
    @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // Do nothing. Do not call the superclass method--that would start a layout pass
    // on this view's children. PieChart lays out its children in onSizeChanged().
    Log.e("DrawView", "DrawView.onLayout: " + l + ", " + t + ", " + r + ", " + b);

    if ( mIconContainerView != null && mArrowBitmap != null ) {
        // set the icon container margin    
        float fHeight = this.getHeight();
        float fScale = fHeight / mArrowBitmap.getHeight();
        float fArrowWidth = mArrowBitmap.getWidth() * fScale;
        float fArrowHeight = mArrowBitmap.getHeight() * fScale;
        Log.d("DockView", "DockView.init: " + fArrowWidth + ", " + fArrowHeight );
        ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mIconContainerView.getLayoutParams()).setMargins((int)fArrowWidth, 0, (int)fArrowWidth, 0);
        this.requestLayout();
    }

    int iChildCount = this.getChildCount();
    for ( int i = 0; i < iChildCount; i++ ) {
        View pChild = this.getChildAt(i);
        pChild.layout(0, 0, pChild.getMeasuredWidth(), pChild.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

CustomView.onDraw

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

//      mBgColor = Color.CYAN;
//      Log.e("DockView", "DockView.onDraw: " + mBgColor);
    Log.e("DockView", "DockView.onDraw: width: " + this.getWidth() + " height: " + this.getHeight());

//      debugChildren( (RelativeLayout) ((RelativeLayout)this.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0) );
    debugChildren( ((RelativeLayout)this.getChildAt(0)) );

    // draw the background
    canvas.drawColor( mBgColor );

    float fWidth = this.getWidth();     // View's width
    float fHeight = this.getHeight();   // View's height

    {
        // draw the dock
        float fTop = (2 * fHeight) / 3.0f;
        Shader shader = new LinearGradient( 0, fTop, 0, fHeight, mDockTopGradientColor, mDockBottomGradientColor, TileMode.CLAMP );
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        canvas.drawRect( new RectF( 0, fTop, fWidth, fHeight ), paint );
    }

// moved to onLayout
//      if ( mIconContainerView != null && mArrowBitmap != null ) {
//          // set the icon container margin        
//          float fScale = fHeight / mArrowBitmap.getHeight();
//          float fArrowWidth = mArrowBitmap.getWidth() * fScale;
//          float fArrowHeight = mArrowBitmap.getHeight() * fScale;
//          Log.d("DockView", "DockView.init: " + fArrowWidth + ", " + fArrowHeight );
//              ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mIconContainerView.getLayoutParams()).setMargins((int)fArrowWidth, 0, (int)fArrowWidth, 0);
//          this.requestLayout();
//      }

    if ( mArrowBitmap != null ) {
        // draw the arrow
//          canvas.drawBitmap(mArrowBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        float fScale = fHeight / mArrowBitmap.getHeight();
        float fDrawnWidth = mArrowBitmap.getWidth() * fScale;
        float fDrawnHeight = mArrowBitmap.getHeight() * fScale;
//          float fLeft = fWidth - fDrawnWidth;
//          float fTop = 0.0f;
//          float fRight = fWidth;
//          float fBottom = fDrawnHeight;
//          Log.d("DockView", "DockView.onDraw: (" + fLeft + ", " + fTop + ", " + fRight + ", " + fBottom + ")");
        canvas.drawBitmap(mArrowBitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, fDrawnWidth, fDrawnHeight), null);    // Left arrow
        Log.d("DockView", "DockView.onDraw: (" + 0 + ", " + 0 + ", " + fDrawnWidth + ", " + fDrawnHeight + ")");
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(-1,1);
        canvas.translate(-fWidth, 0);
//          canvas.drawBitmap(mArrowBitmap, null, new RectF(fLeft, fTop, fRight, fBottom), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mArrowBitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, fDrawnWidth, fDrawnHeight), null);    // Right arrow, flipped
        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```